# how to get confirmation that a page has been seen using php/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, confirmation

I'm looking for some guidance on the best way to carry out a task.
I have 2 users where user1 validates some information which then becomes available to user2.
I want to know the best way to let user1 know that user2 has seen the page they have validated?
I'm also using a database to store the information that user1 makes available to user2.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there a way of checking if someone has looked at a page or clicked a link?
I was thinking along the lines of if I can check if user2 has clicked a link I can maybe update a database field with a token of viewed/ not viewed.

Many thanks

Comment: Cookie on user1 and user2. Then in the page you can read the cookie to see if it's user1 or 2 who is there and update the database with a value

Comment: Is there only 1 user that can validate the page, and 1 user that has to see that page?  Then you could add a field 'validated' and a field 'seen' to your page records.  And indeed, after the SELECT, you update the 'seen' or 'validated' field.

Comment: @user keep in mind that cookies can be deleted and can be disabeld. It's not bullitproof, but if you can somewhat control user1 and 2, then it should work "ok"

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay how would I know that they have seen the page though?

Comment: Is user1 also able to see the page? Is that "the problem". If user1 is not able to see the page, maybe you can just update the variable as soon as the page is loaded?

Comment: Its basically information entered by user1 is then validated.. which is sent to user2 who can see that information plus extra stuff that is generated elsewhere, I think I'm going to go with the cookie route! thanks again @Andreas